# How to resolve error in tenserflow installation caused by other packages version

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, pip

I executed the command `pip install tensorflow` .
But the installation is giving me following error. Below is the part of log

```
ERROR: After October 2020 you may experience errors when installing or updating packages. This is because pip will change the way that it resolves dependency conflicts.

We recommend you use --use-feature=2020-resolver to test your packages with the new resolver before it becomes the default.

tf-nightly 2.5.0.dev20201102 requires grpcio~=1.32.0, but you'll have grpcio 1.33.2 which is incompatible.
tf-nightly 2.5.0.dev20201102 requires numpy~=1.19.2, but you'll have numpy 1.18.5 which is incompatible.
tensorflow-federated-nightly 0.17.0.dev20201031 requires absl-py~=0.9.0, but you'll have absl-py 0.11.0 which is incompatible.
tensorflow-federated-nightly 0.17.0.dev20201031 requires grpcio~=1.29.0, but you'll have grpcio 1.33.2 which is incompatible.
Successfully installed numpy-1.18.5
```

Ps I had uninstalled numpy, grpcio, absl-py before executing the above command.

Comment: Uninstall `tf-nightly` and the rest of the `*-nightly` packages first.

Comment: @hoefling that worked. Thanks

Comment: @hoefling can you please add that as an answer or vote to close?